# SVM - passing a string to the CountVectorizer in Python vectorizes each character?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, vectorization

I have a working SVM and the CountVectorizer works fine when the input to the `transform` function is a list of strings. However, if I just pass one string to it, the vectorizer iterates through each character in the string and vectorizes each one, even though I set the `analyzer` parameter to `word` when constructing the `CountVectorizer`.

```
for x in range(0,3):
        test=raw_input("Type a message to classify: ")
        v=vectorizer.transform(test).toarray()
        print(v)
        print(len(v))
        print(svm.predict(vectorizer.transform(test).toarray()))
```

I'm able to fix this issue by changing the second line in the above code to:

```
test=[raw_input("Type a message to classify: ")]
```

But this seems strange to have a 1-item list. Isn't there a better way to do this without constructing a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It expects a list or array of documents so when you pass in a single string it assumes that each element of that string is a document (ie: a character).

Try changing `svm.predict(vectorizer.transform(test).toarray())` to `svm.predict(vectorizer.transform([test]).toarray())`

PS: The `toarray()` part is not going to scale well as you use a real-world corpus. SVMs in sklearn can operate on sparse matrices so I'd drop that part all together.

Comment: Great, thanks! It was just really odd that in the docs it seems to accept a string as input http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: Where does it say that? It lists the input as needing to be an iterable of documents: `An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.`

Comment: I saw `input : string {‘filename’, ‘file’, ‘content’}` and `Otherwise the input is expected to be the sequence strings or bytes items are expected to be analyzed directly.` as iterating through the string like an array of length 1, especially considering my vectorizer is set to use word, not character n-grams. But now I see what you're referring to which makes much more sense! I wonder what input does then.